# How do I route specific traffic for a work domain through my wifi interface?

Tags: fedora

I would like to route all traffic for `mycompany.com` through my wifi interface (wlp7s0) and use my ethernet interface (eno1) for all other traffic. My ethernet adapter is much faster and I would prefer to use that for most of my network traffic. However, in order to access certain work resources I need to route traffic through the wifi interface.

Is this possible on Fedora 30?

Comment: Assuming mycompany.com has fixed public IP addresses, just add the necessary routes with `ip route add ...`. There are various way to make that setup permanent depending on what kind of networking you use (systemd? Classic ifup/ifdown? Etc.).

Comment: I need to route multiple sub domains through my wifi adapter. Such as wwwin.mycompany.com, jira.mycompany.com etc. Can this be accomplished with 'ip route add'?

Comment: Routing works on the basis of numerical IPs or IP prefixes (IP ranges of a certain shape), not domain names. So the answer depends on how the IP addresses are assigned for the various *.mycompany.com domain names, and in particular how static this assignment is.